# Writing custom qhash() function for my class

Tags: c++, qt, qhash

I would like to use a `QHash<MyOwnClass&, MyOwnEnum>` (as a member of `MyOwnClass` if it does matter). Docs say that one should define a global `qhash(MyOwnClass&)` function. OK, for example:

**globals.h:**

```
#pragma once
#include "myOwnClass.h"
#include <QHashFunctions>

class MyOwnClass;

inline uint qHash(MyOwnClass& clz);
```

**globals.cpp:**

```
#include "globals.h"

inline uint qHash(MyOwnClass& clz) {
    return qHash(clz.getSomeQStringMember());
}
```

Where should I include my `globals.h`, so that the compiler will be able to see and use it?

I'm using MSVS2015 and Qt 5.8.
I believe this question is silly and has very simple solution, as long as the answer would help many others like me.

Comment: The Qt function is named `qHash`, not `qhash`.

Comment: Big letters matter!

Comment: @Igor @dtech my terrific fault.. But the IDE still shows errors. `(C2665 'qHash': none of the 22 overloads could convert all the argument types ...\qhashfunctions.h 110)`. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a custom type that you will be using in a hash, it will be best to simply declare the function in the same header which declares `MyOwnClass`. It goes hand in hand with that class after all, you don't need a `globals.h` in order to have a global function, it just needs to be in the global scope and not be static.

You will also have to `#include <QHash>` where you define your hash function (the implementation), so it can have access to the existing hash implementations.

Edit: I see that you include `#include <QHashFunctions>` which should give you the function to hash a `QString`. So you probably need to clean and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

@dtech 's answer is worth to be read but it did not solve my issue completely.

One cannot use a non-const reference as a key in `QHash`, so I should declare it as `QHash<const MyOwnClass&, MyOwnEnum>` and define function `qHash(const MyOwnClass& clz)` (as long as an equality operator, of course).

Comment: "One cannot use a non-const reference as a key" - actually that's perfectly possible. The problem is not that the key isn't a constant, but that it depends on a non constant, if `SomeQStringMember` is to change, that would break the hash table.